# How do i work out if this matrix is diagonally dominted?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

[image: Matrix]

I am having trouble answering these two questions:
(a) Is matrix A diagonally dominant? 
(b) Find the spectral radius of the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iteration matrices.

Comment: Please give us the precise wording of the question that you're trying to answer.  It is clear that your matrix is diagonally dominant (per the definition given in the answer below).  Does that answer your question as far as diagonal dominance goes, or is something still unclear?  Regarding the spectral radius: are they asking you to compute the exact spectral radius without using a calculator?  If not, then what exactly are they asking you to do with the spectral radius?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Here is the exact wording:                                                   
(a) Is matrix A diagonally dominant?
(b) Find the spectral radius of the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iteration matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) if in every row, the absolute value of the main diagonal is greater than the sum of absolute values of the rest of the row. In other words,
$$
|a_{ii}| > \sum_{k\ne i} |a_{ik}|.
$$

Some examples are
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3 & 1 \\ 4 & -5 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -3\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

[Spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) is the largest size of the eigenvalue of that matrix.

For example, the spectral radius of 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -3\end{pmatrix}
$$
is $\max \{|1|, |-5|, |-3|\} = 5$.

To find the spectral radius, one way is to find all the eigenvalues, compute their sizes and take the largest one.